# jaxb bindings cannot find schema

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

Hello I have the following bindings:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc simplify annox" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="3235"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
     <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="jaxb/niem2/socd-x.xsd"></jaxb:bindings>
      <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='SurveyControlAndDataMessageType']">
        <annox:annotate>
          <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="SurveyControlAndDataMessageType"/>
        </annox:annotate>
      </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

My bindings file is in `src/main/resources` and the xsd is in `src/main/resources/jaxb/niem2`.  However, wenever I build I get:

> com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId:
>   file:/C:/work/MOJO/MOJOInterfaces/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb;
>   lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 60;

"file:/C:/work/MOJO/MOJOInterfaces/src/main/resources/jaxb/niem2/socd-x.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/C:/work/MOJO/MOJOInterfaces/src/main/resources/MaestroGeoData.xsd?

This is the relevant portion of the pom

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <id>jaxb-generate-workload</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>MaestroSdfAndWorkloadTypes.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generatePackage>mojo.interfaces.mocs.input</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-mocs</generateDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <id>jaxb-generate-niem2</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                                <arg>-npa</arg>
                                <arg>-verbose</arg>
                            </args>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>jaxb/niem2/*.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-niem/META-INF/jaxb-niem2.episode</episodeFile>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-niem</generateDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                        <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
                        <arg>-Xmergeable</arg>
                        <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
                    </args>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.9.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration> 
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>                    
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I verified the xsd exists on the drive, any other ideas?

Thanks,

**Edit:**
So I figured out that it's having issues because it's using the same binding file for each of the executions that I have in the jaxb plugin.  Now I need to figure out how to get it to only pick up the binding file for the execution it should be using it for.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the binding.jxb in its own directory and specifying that directory in the Execution that should make use of that binding, e.g.:

```
<execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>jaxb-generate-niem2</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                             <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                            <arg>-npa</arg>
                            <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        </args>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/jaxb/niem</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/jaxb/niem/binding</bindingDirectory>
                        <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-niem/META-INF/jaxb-niem2.episode</episodeFile>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-niem</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```